# Show notification bar in Firefox to install an extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

If I go to this page: http://page2rss.com/page?url=www.google.com/ it will be asked to install an extension for Chrome. I wonder is there a similar way to do with Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "notification bar" is part of the web page - the web page detects that the browser is Chrome and that the user doesn't have their extension installed, so it displays that message. The browser has nothing to do with that. The only "trick" here is making the Install button trigger the installation. This is of course [possible with Firefox as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Installing_Extensions_and_Themes_From_Web_Pages).